# DB2 running into SQLCODE=-954 when reading CLOB

Tags: hibernate, db2

In my application I am calling a DB2 stored procedure several times which is generating JSON. It will be called in a loop several times, nearly in 20MB steps by defining the offset.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        StoredProcedureQuery sp=
                em.createStoredProcedureQuery("CREATE_JSON");
        StoredProcedureQuery q= createStoredProcedureQuery
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("result", Clob.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("offset", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        q.setParameter("offset", i*50000);
        q.execute();
        Clob data = (Clob) registerStoredProcedureParameter.getOutputParameterValue("result");
    }
```

This result in

```
ERROR: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-954, SQLSTATE=57011, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.8.86
```

But when I am calling once, than its working fine. How can I solve it?

Comment: See the recommendations at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0750-sql0999#sql0954c

Comment: Additionally you must upgrade your db2jcc4.jar , as you are using  and antique version 4.8.86 (circa v9.7 more than a decade ago). You need to be using db2jcc4.jar at a currently supported release e.g. 4.32.28 (available by download indirectly via https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads

Comment: How can I read current value for APPLHEAPSZ?, is it possible to free heap after first call?

Comment: Ask your DBA for configuration help, if you want to have APPLHEAPSZ adjusted (other parameters might also need adjusting). This is configuration not programming.  Refer to the free online Db2 Knowledge Centre for your Db2-server version for details, e.g. either use command line on the Db2-server `db2 get database configuration for..` or query via SQL via admin view (depending on your Db2-server version) see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-dbcfg-database-configuration-parameter-information#r0022028__view_22028

Comment: Is it possible to copy the JSON from the stored procedure into a shared directory?